# mongoexport not working if you add query of selection

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

If you want to export any collections of any of your mongodb database, you can use `mongoexport` command. For example:

```
mongoexport --db dbname --collection collectionName --query '{"fields":1}' --out output.json
```

However, if you add any of selection criteria to the query, `mongoexport` command doesn't work. For example, if you run the following command:

```
mongoexport --db dbname --collection collectionName --query '{},{"fields":0}' --out output.json
```

the resultant JSON file includes data of every field, despite me excluding a filed named `fields`.

So why does this such strange behavior occur? And how can I fix it?

For your information, `db.colName.find({},{"fields":0})` in mongoDB shell works as usual.

I'm on MongoDB 2.4.3 and OS X 10.9.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `--query` argument takes only query and there is no option to pass projection. See [`mongoexport --query`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--query) in [official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/). If you want to use a projection you have to add [`--fields`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--fields) option

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I overlooked `--fields` option. Now everything is working well.